# Cannot add column in MySQL Workbenck ERD Linux

Tags: linux, debian, mysql-workbench

I installed MySQL Workbench in Debian Jessie from the repository. I need to create a new ERD, but I can not add a new column to the table, but the Windows version columns are added without problems. Help solve the problem.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have this problem too..